# Can the WPF Storyboard applied to a UIElement be disovered from the UIElement (in code)?

Tags: wpf, storyboard, uielement

Is there a way to interrogate a `UIElement` to determine which Storyboards are affecting it?

For example, `Storyboard` resources can be defined in a number of places (eg Application.Resources, Window.Resources, Control.Resources).  If you have a reference to a control being affected by a `Storyboard` (say a `RotateTransform`), is there any way to interrogate the control to discover that `Storyboard`?

What I don't want is to obtain the reference of the `Storyboard` simply by knowing it's name.

Comment: I don't think the UIElements know about Storyboards at all, But the Storyboards will know about the Elements through the `Target` property. So perhaps you could go backward and iterrogate the storyboards for the UIElement you want

Comment: Interrogate the Storyboards where though @sa_ddam213?  They could be defined anywhere!  Is there a central Storyboards location?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to know what you asking, however you can use following code :

Suppose "btn" is the control for which you are searching `Storyboard`.

```
  Button btn = new Button();
        List<Storyboard> lst = new List<Storyboard>();
        foreach (var item in this.Resources)
        {
            if (item is Storyboard)
            {
                Storyboard temp = item as Storyboard;

                foreach (var animation in temp.Children)
                {
                    if (animation.GetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty) == btn)
                    {
                        lst.Add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This assumes the Storyboard is defined in "this", which may not be the case.

Comment: Sure @Shivamcv.  My point is though that there are any number of NameScopes that could contribute the Storyboard between where you are performing the look up and application resources.  You don't necessarily know each place to check, so this is not a complete solution.